# Sending custom audience data to facebook via facebook ads api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of email ids and mobile number. I want to send these to facebook for look-alike targeting and exclusion of some profiles.

I have earlier worked on graph api and know how this works.

After reading the documentation and in the process of its implementation, I came to know that I need to copy https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk to my site and add contents to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/examples/custom_audiences.php file. The content of the file:

```
define('SDK_DIR', __DIR__ . '/..'); // Path to the SDK directory
$loader = include SDK_DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use FacebookAds\Api;
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
// use the namespace for Custom Audiences and Fields
use FacebookAds\Object\CustomAudience;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CustomAudienceFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\CustomAudienceTypes;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\CustomAudienceSubtypes;
// Create a custom audience object, setting the parent to be the account id
$audience = new CustomAudience(null, $account_id);
$audience->setData(array(
  CustomAudienceFields::NAME => 'My Custom Audiece',
  CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION => 'Lots of people',
  CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE => CustomAudienceSubtypes::CUSTOM,
));
// Create the audience
$audience->create();
echo "Audience ID: " . $audience->id."\n";
// Assuming you have an array of emails:
// NOTE: The SDK will hash (SHA-2) your data before submitting
// it to Facebook servers
$emails = getAllEmails();
$audience->addUsers($emails, CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL);
$audience->read(array(CustomAudienceFields::APPROXIMATE_COUNT));
echo "Estimated Size:"
  . $audience->{CustomAudienceFields::APPROXIMATE_COUNT}."\n";
```

1. Since, I downloaded the file, what does `$loader = include SDK_DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';`
    mean?
2. How can I test the above code?
3. In case of targeting with email and mobile to the same profile id, what will happen?

Comment: If you download it you need to read the code and understand it before you run random code you downloaded from the internet

Comment: Noted. New to PHP, new to facebook api, thanks for the suggestion. :) :D

Comment: @learner did you manage to run the code?